# AHK - Sleep inside a function doesn't work (2)

Tags: autohotkey

I have read previous similar article and tried as there adviced. But it doesn't work for me. Or I missing something? I tried many syntax variations.

```
keydelay := 1000

^z::
    PlayQueue([1,2,3,"q","e"])
return

PlayQueue(queue)
{
    global keydelay
    for i, k in queue
        Send, %k%
        Sleep %keydelay%
}
```

Its just fires instantly without delays :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only omit `{ }` if you have a single line statement.
Your for loop's body has two lines, so you'll need braces.

```
PlayQueue(queue)
{
    global keydelay
    for i, k in queue
    {
        Send, %k%
        Sleep, %keydelay%
    } 
}
```